# How would this (x,y) function look like?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

let $g:B=[0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be

$g(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{y^2} & 0 <x<y\leq 1\\
                      -\frac{1}{x^2}  & 0<y<x\leq 1 \\
                         0 &else \end{cases}$

Could someone please show me how this function would look like? I am having difficulties imaging a two dimensional piecewise function. I do not know how to draw it with a plotter

Comment: https://help.geogebra.org/topic/piecewise-3d-graphics may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geogebra 3D formula:
`a(x,y)=If(0<x ∧ x<y ∧ y≤1, (1)/(y^(2)), 1≥x ∧ x>y ∧ y>0, -((1)/(x^(2))), 0)`

The input space is the blue/grey plane (more specifically, the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ on the grey plane), the output space is the blue axis. Your function is in 3 parts. The line $x=y$ maps to 0, the part above that line on the input plane maps to $1/y^2$ (the part above the grey plane), the part below that line on the input plane maps to $-1/x^2$ (the part below the grey plane)

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Would f be unbounded? And usually $1/x^2$ is not continuous at x=0. would this also be a problem here? Or not, since $0<x<y\leq 1$? Even though it is defined on [0,1] x [0,1]

Comment: $1/x^2$ is more than non-continuous at 0, it's undefined! Here, your function has a value for $x = 0$ and $y=0$ only because of your "else" statement. So indeed, it's better to say that the kernel (place where your function maps to 0) is the "chicken's foot" of 3 segments ($x = 0$, $x = y$ and $y = 0$). Also, $f$ is indeed unbounded, because its image (set of possible output values) goes to either (in this case, both) positive or negative infinity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification :)